Semi-thriller/drama with a prostitute, money and betrayal
I'm looking for a movie with a prostitute who carries a bag with an S letter hanging (so the girl's name started with S). One guy is trying to track the girl down and ends up having some kind of relationship with her. This girl betrays him with his co-worker and takes his money, but after all that guy manages to track them both down.
The hooker with a guy escaped to Europe, maybe Poland, Ukraine or Czech. In the very beginning the main guy was working late and his co-worker offered him some weed and they smoked together. This co-worker pretended to be his pal but screwed him up later on. 
I think it was an American movie. The genre is drama / semi-thriller, about 6,5-7/10 at imdb i'd guess. It's not too old, somewhere between 2006-2009 maybe. I've been trying to find this movie again, but just can't remember its name.

Not quite sure what "a bag with a letter hanging" is. Can you explain? (And was the movie American?)

Ah sorry, I meant S letter hanging, so the girls name started with S. I think it was american movie. The hooker with a guy escaped in europe, maybe in Poland, Ukraine or Czech. In the very beginning the main guy was working late and his co-worker offered him some weed and they smoked together. This co-worker pretended to be his pal but screwed him up later on.

Ah, I think I know what you're looking for. I might have answered a similar question before, I'll just look it up.

I think you're looking for Deception from 2008:

Timid accountant Jonathan McQuarry (Ewan McGregor) is an auditor working out of New York. One night while working late in a boardroom he meets a charismatic lawyer, Wyatt Bose (Hugh Jackman), who befriends him over a joint. After a long conversation, Jonathan takes the subway home where he has a brief encounter with a blonde woman (Michelle Williams) while waiting on the train.

Michelle Williams' character is part of some secret sex club and she's nicknamed 'S' because there's an S-shaped pendant hanging on her handbag. I think the rest of the plot fits too: Wyatt cons Jonathan, they're fighting over money and there are scenes in Europe (Madrid). Here's the trailer:



[I suggested this movie as an answer before, but the question was quite different.)

Wow,  I provided this movie as an answer to this question but totally didn't connect that letter on the purse part here.

That is the movie! Awesome work man. Haha, well, we pay attention on different things I see :-) I thought Im gonna get get my question deleted and IP banned. BIG thanks to you mate!!
